# Non-object-oriented game tutorials

Tags: oop

I've been tasked with writing an essay extolling the virtues of object oriented programming and creating an accompanying game to demonstrate them.

My initial idea is to find a tutorial for a simple game written in a programming language which does not follow the OOP paradigm (or written in an OOP language but not in an OOP way) and recreate it in an OOP way using either C# or Java (haven't yet decided). This would then allow me to make concrete comparisons between the two.

The game doesn't have to be anything complex; Tetris, Pong, etc. that sort of thing. The problem I've had so far is finding a suitable tutorial, any suggestions?

Comment: You don't say what paradigm you want to use as an alternative. Just look up tutorials for functional programming, it's one of the more popular alternatives. Give Haskell a try. It'll take a bit to wrap your head around, but it's fun. However, this isn't the site for people to answer with specific tutorials. Only you know the right tutorial for you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "object-oriented"? You're not going to find very many programs in any language that don't collect related data into object or employ data hiding (they even do it in C libraries all the time). So what is it that you're not looking for?

Comment: By "does not follow OOP paradigm" you mean do not use inherence and things like that or don't even use classes etc. (i guess you can use class since you talked about Java and C#). Maybe you should take a look at Entity/System based games. http://t-machine.org/index.php/2007/09/03/entity-systems-are-the-future-of-mmog-development-part-1/

Comment: You want an A? Write a paper about why the underlying assumption of this task is incorrect. OOP is not more or less virtuous than any other properly constructed paradigm's approach to game code. It depends on the game in question, and different paradigms would ideally be used throughout a game's construction depending on the need. Component-Base Programming is best for entities like the player and enemies, Aspect Oriented Programming is best for many over-arching systems, [Automata Based Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata-based_programming) is ideal for many kinds of AI.

Comment: @DampeS8N Not disagreeing with the general sentiment, but if the goal is to get high marks on an essay, then I really don't recommend being confrontational about what you interpret your professor's underlying assumptions to be.  Particularly based on second-hand expertise.

Comment: @TrevorPowell You are correct. The expertise should be first hand, and the tone should be not confrontational but exploratory and only the conclusion should be that the underlying assumption of the task was incorrect. Something along the lines of "After careful testing and analysis of these differing approaches to these various problems, I can only conclude that OOP is one tool among many. Each of these tools has merit and a job that they perform best at. Screwdrivers can be used as hammers and crowbars, but it is better to use the right tool for the job." Also wise to show jobs OOP does best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need something non-OOP to contrast with, which isn't just a bunch of spaghetti in which any clean or well structured code will be an improvement. Here are a few links to non-object oriented approaches that you can look at.

Functional programming in a few flavors:

- [Purely Functional Retrogames](http://prog21.dadgum.com/23.html)
- [Composing Reactive Animations](http://conal.net/fran/tutorial.htm)

Declarative or rule-based systems, like prolog or Inform 7 for text games:

- [Adventure in Prolog](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/)
- [Inform 7](http://inform7.com/learn/) is based on a novel concept of rulebooks.

Even with OOP it's not obvious that an inheritance heavy class hierarchy is the only approach. Component entity systems are another way to structure your game objects:

- [Entity Systems wiki](http://entity-systems.wikidot.com/)

Comment: +1 for the first sentence, and for a generally concise and informative answer.

Answer (score 1):

A really solid example would be [Frag](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Frag) as FPS written in Haskell. However it will be too complex to grasp without good Haskell knowledge. As for tutorials based on non OOP game programming then [this series of articles will explain Entity Systems](http://t-machine.org/index.php/2007/09/03/entity-systems-are-the-future-of-mmog-development-part-1/).

I would point out though that starting with the conclusion and working back is going to be a pretty terrible way to write an article. In fact if you read [this article talking about Entity Systems in 'Tony Hawk' games](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/) there is a solid case to be made for the idea that OOP is NOT the best technique to use in performant game design.

Good luck on your journey, I hope the articles are illuminating!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try making a text based game where all the commands are if else type statements. Maybe a more liner game would be best, think something like a choose your own adventure book. That would be a simple example of procedural programming. I suppose you could argue that variables of any sort are objects but they have those even in assembly so I'd say they are okay. This may even be the time to use the dreaded goto statement as even though it may not be best practice it would work in this situation

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a couple of programming tutorials based on non OOP languages, mostly C.  If you Google "C game programming tutorial" or similar then you should find them, however there are certainly more tutorials for OOP languages - after all, tutorials are aimed at beginners, and for beginners modern OOP languages (especially those like C# and Java) are easier to get started with than languages like C.

If I were you I would do the reverse however - write a simple game using OOP techniques, and then work backwards converting the same code so that it doesn't rely on any OOP features. With a simple game this should be quite achievable and if you use something like C/C++ a lot of your code will look very similar in both versions.